# If $x^3, y^3$ commute for all $x, y\in G$, show that $H=\{h\in G|(|h|,3)=1\}$ is an abelian subgroup of $G$. What happens if $3\mapsto n\in\Bbb N$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, coprime

*If this question is too broad, then I'm sorry.*

[This appears to be new to MSE.](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Coprime%2C%20%2C%20%24x%5E3y%5E3%3Dy%5E3x%5E3%24&p=1)

I'm reading *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra,"* by Gallian.

This is Exercise 44 of the supplementary exercises for chapters 1-4 *ibid.* **I'd like to answer this question using the tools available in the textbook so far.** (A free copy of the textbook is available online.)

### The Question:

> Suppose $G$ is a group and $x^3y^3=y^3x^3$ for every $x$ and $y$ in $G$. Let $H=\{ x\mid \,\lvert x\rvert\text{ is relatively prime to }3\}$. Prove that elements of $H$ commute with each other and that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Is your argument valid if $3$ is replaced by an arbitrary positive integer $n$? Explain why or why not.

### Thoughts:

In the textbook, I think $\lvert e\rvert:=1$. Thus $e\in H$.

I want to use the two-step subgroup lemma.

If $h\in H$, then $(\lvert h\rvert, 3)=1$. But it has been shown in the textbook previously (I think as an exercise) that for all $g\in G$ we have $\lvert g^{-1}\rvert=\lvert g\rvert$, so that $(\lvert h^{-1}\rvert, 3)=1$. Hence $h^{-1}\in H$.

The next step is to show that for any $h_1, h_2\in H$, we have $h_1h_2\in H$.

My problem is that I'm unsure of what the order of a product of elements is in terms of the orders of the elements in the product. For example, in the symmetric group $\mathcal{S}_3$, we have $\lvert (12)\rvert=2$ and $\lvert (13)\rvert=2$ but $\lvert (13)(12)\rvert=\lvert (123)\rvert=3$.

I gather that the coprimality is important and that if $n$ is not prime, $H$ might not be a subgroup; I'm not sure though. That is just a vague recollection of undergraduate algebra speaking . . .

---

How to prove $H$ is abelian, I don't know.

---

I'm aware that I haven't used the hypothesis that  $x^3y^3=y^3x^3$ for every $x$ and $y$ in $G$.

---

Please help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We begin by noting that the hypothesis $x^3 y^3 = y^3 x^3$ can actually be strengthened to 
$$(x^3 y^3)^n = (x^3)^n (y^3)^n \text{ for all } x,y \in G \text{ and } n \in \mathbb{N}. \tag{$\star$}
$$
The stronger version can be proved by induction. 
Perhaps it is worth commenting on the inductive step.  If we assume that  $(x^3 y^3)^{n-1} = (x^3)^{n-1} (y^3)^{n-1}$, then we write
$$(x^3 y^3)^n = (x^3 y^3)^{n-1} (x^3 y^3)$$
and we repeatedly 
use the given hypothesis to move the last factor of $x^3$ across each of the $n-1$ interior copies of $y^3$ to give
$$
\begin{split}
(x^3 y^3)^n &=
 x^{3(n-1)} y^{3(n-2)} (y^3x^3) y^3 = x^{3(n-1)} y^{3(n-2)} (x^3 y^3) y^3 \\
&= x^{3(n-1)} y^{3(n-3)} (y^3 x^3) y^6 = \dots = x^{3n} y^{3n}.
\end{split}$$

In order to apply the hypothesis $x^3y^3 = y^3 x^3$ as well as the stronger analogue, we use the following lemma.

**Lemma 1:** If $\text{gcd}(|h|, 3) = 1$, then $h = g^3$ for some $g \in G$.

**Proof:** If $\text{gcd}(|h|, 3) = 1$, then there exist $k, \ell \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $1 = k|h| + 3 \ell$.  It follows that we have
$$
\begin{split}
h = h^1 = h^{k|h|} \cdot h^{3 \ell} = \left(h^{\ell}\right)^3.
& \\
& \square
\end{split}
$$

Having proved the lemma, one can prove that $H$ is closed under multiplication as follows: let $h_1, h_2 \in H$.  Then there are $g_1, g_2 \in G$ so that $h_1 = g_1^3$ and $h_2 = g_2^3$.  To prove that $h_1 h_2 \in H$, we must show that $\text{gcd}(|h_1 h_2|,3) = 1$.  For this, it suffices to show that 
$(h_1 h_2)^{|h_1| |h_2|} = 1$ because this will mean that $|h_1 h_2|$ divides the product of $|h_1|$ and $|h_2|$.  To  show that $(h_1 h_2)^{|h_1| |h_2|} = 1$, we use $(\star)$ to give
$$
(h_1 h_2)^{|h_1| |h_2|} = (g_1^3 g_2^3)^{|h_1| |h_2|} = (g_1^3)^{|h_1| |h_2|} (g_2^3)^{|h_1| |h_2|} = h_1^{|h_1| |h_2|} h_2^{|h_1| |h_2|} = 1. 
$$
This concludes our proof that $H$ is closed under multiplication.

Having proved that $H$ is a subgroup, it is immediate that $H$ is abelian, because every element of $H$ is a cube in $G$, and we are given that cubes commute in $G$.

---

Edit: I forgot to address what happens if we replace $3$ by an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  If we replace $3$ by $n$, then the argument still works: we can still see that any $h \in G$ so that $(|h|, n) = 1$ must be a perfect $n$th power.  Using this, we can still show that if $h_1, h_2$ have 
$(|h_1|, n) = 1 = (|h_2|, n)$, then the order of $h_1 h_2$ divides the product of their orders, which means it is also coprime to $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the edit to what was an already very informative answer :)